# How do I loop over a map object's 2ND value in reverse?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a map and I am using a for loop to loop through it, but it only gives me the first value,.in ascending order. Any help appreciated!

Comment: By `map`, do you mean `dict`?  If that's the case, it has no order...

Comment: @mgilson nope. Python 3 has a map object, which is like map in functional programming. Not sure which he refers to though

Comment: [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) exists prior to Python 3, but it's a function -- there's not much sense in the phrase "map object" if OP's referring to the function.

Comment: Can you add your code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not very clear what your asking, but I took my best guess. Next time **try to post some of your already done code!**

```
>>> mydict = {'a': 1, 'b': 89, 'c': 56, 'd': 9123, 'e':-23}
>>> mylist = []
>>> for k in mydict:
...     mylist.append(mydict[k])
... 
>>> mylist.sort()
>>> mylist.reverse()
>>> mylist
[9123, 89, 56, 1, -23]
>>>
```

**Explanation:**

Lines

1. Set `mydict` to some value of numbers (because you want it in reverse)
2. Set `mylist` to a blank list
3. Loop over the **first** value of the dict
4. Use the **first** value to get the second value with `mydict[k]`.
5. Append that to `mylist`
6. Use `mylist.sort()` to sort in ascending order
7. Use `mylist.reverse()` to reverse it.

Comment: This is a pretty verbose solution for something that can be done in a single line.  Also, it's wasteful to iterate over keys and do a dict lookup for each element.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by ascending order?  You could sort them:

**Python 2.7**

```
for v in sorted(map.itervalues()):
   print v
```

**Python 3**

```
for v in sorted(map.values()):
   print v
```

If instead you wanted keys to be sorted, try:

```
for _, v in sorted(map.items()):
   print v
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by map you mean a `dict`, by "first value" you mean key, and by "second value" you mean value?

You can use `.iteritems()` to iterate over key/value pairs instead of just keys

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    print "key:", k
    print "value:", v
```

Or `.itervalues()` to iterate over just the values:

```
for v in d.valueitems():
    print "value:", v
```

There's no way to apply ordering to a dict's items directly -- iteration over a dict can occur in any order. You can however iterate over a sorted `iteritems()`:

```
for k, v in sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda k, v: v):
    print "key:", k
    print "value:", v
```

Or just the values:

```
for v in sorted(d.valueitems()):
    print "value:", v
```